The problem is with rounding the edges
As you can see in the screenshot, I'm performing a Boolean operation using the SVG outline of the object on a CUBE, then applying the Bevel modifier to get the edges rounding i need

But as soon as I scale the CUBE to the size I need, my edge rounding operation turns into a mess.


You should Apply Scale with Ctrl+A.
